# Error al hacer fetch a api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Este es mi código:

```
consultarApi = () => {
    const termino = this.state.termino;
    const pagina = this.state.pagina;
    var url = "url;
   // console.log(url);
    url = url + "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
    //console.log(url);
    url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
    url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
    url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME= *este es mi id de la api, que es válido";
    url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
    url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
    url += '&keywords='+termino;
    url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=20";
    fetch(url)
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
        .then(resultado => console.log(resultado))
    //console.log(url);
    this.setState({
        url : url
    });       
}
```

Access to fetch at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Este error me aparece, qué puedo hacer? soy novato aún en el tema.

Answer (score 1):

Felipe creo que entiendo al 100% tu pregunta asi que con el fin de poderte ayudar asumiré varias cosas, asi que asumo cosas que no estan pasando solo comentalas y puedo actualizar la respuesta.

El error que estas viendo se debe a que el servidor al cual estas haciendo la petición (usando fetch) esta en un dominio diferente. Por ejemplo tu llamada es desde localhost:3000 y tu servidor esta en el dominio localhost:5000. Para que este error desaparezca necesitas configurar tu servidor para que acepte peticiones desde localhost:3000.

Este error se podría decir es nativo del navegador y lo hace por razones de seguridad. Puedes leer un poco mas en el siguiente enlace

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Por otra parte, dependiendo de que lenguaje uses en el backend y que framework hay varias librerías que te pueden ayudar a configurar tu servidor para aceptar peticiones desde ese dominio (localhost:3000). Por ejemplo si estas usando nodejs, existen un paquete llamada cors que puede ayudarte a configurar estas cabeceras que el servidor debe de enviar.

Te dejo un ejemplo

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
```